# When is too soon to confront a user with a form?

Tags: signup-signon, landing-page

I have been in the concept stage of a project aimed at getting people to share their loves and passions. I am wondering if creating a landing page that consists of a "fill in the blanks" style form (a) is too confrontational. My other option is to lead the user through some examples that also explain the site before prompting them to share (b).

This is something I plan to a/b test but curious if anyone has an opinion on this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be fine. You are basically dealing with an empty state and you need to provide your users with some content based upon your input.

I think your approach works fine though it might be better for your users to know how you will use the input to generate content. Given below is an example of how a form is a part of a page with a description.

[image]